# Hibernate - Referencing OneToMany without related table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, ddl

I have the following mapping. It works fine. the problem is that Hibernate created 3 tables for that: `request`, `research` and `request_researches`.
`request_researches` is not needed.
I want the foreign key to be inside the `research` table. (`research.request_id`)

```
@Entity
public class Request{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Research.class,cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ResearchEntity> researches = new ArrayList<>();

    //... getters setters
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `@JoinColumn` annotation where you specify the column from the related entity:

```
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Research.class,cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "request_id")
    private List<ResearchEntity> researches = new ArrayList<>();
```